# css: logo: img: float right: being weird: still floating left and showing bgcolor of another div

Tags: css, css-float, graphical-logo

this is just a static page, nothing too frilly. i just want this page to look fine smooshed into a cell-phone, tablet, or on a computer monitor.

http://www.cupcakeshop.com

the logo is 400px wide, i want it to float to the right of the div, but it's staying left. and added to that, it's adopting the background color of the div below it. please help if you see what i'm missing. i am AAA novice at this!

```
<div class="logo">
<a href="http://www.cupcakeshop.com">
<img src="http://www.cupcakeshop.com/images/banner.png">
</a>
</div>
```

and

```
div.logo { width:100%; max-width: 760px; height: 110px; float: right; }
```

what i was hoping to do is have it slightly responsive, in that it would be 400px on a smaller screen and max-width 760px on a pc, where the logo would butt up to the right margin with white background to the left of the logo image. is this doable, without too much complexity?

thanks for your time, audra may

Comment: try `.logo a { float:right; }`

Comment: done! that's moved it over! awesome! thanks! now, any ideas on why the background is being shared from below?

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo a img
{
  float:right
}
```

is what you need:

Check the JS Bin here: http://jsbin.com/usacew/1

Comment: phew! you've saved the day. thanks again. very kind of you to take the time! :)

Comment: @CupcakeShop You're welcome... if it helped you, just check this answer as accepted. By the way: I liked the simple and clean design. It looks good on the iPhone. Wish you success on the market! Would you kindly send me a cupcake?! hahaha just kidding... :)

Comment: haha! i thought i'd make that disclaimer right up front since, for years, we get emails constantly asking for us to cater peoples' weddings and provide their cupcake decorations! i don't know why people never noticed... that's not what we sell. oh well!

Comment: WOW! I should've read the front page... sorry for being one more asking for cupcakes. OK... now I know you're not a bakery! :D